# QTCreator 3.1 design tab not working

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I’m currently using QtCreator 3.1 and qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.1 on Ubuntu 12.04
My project is correctly working, i.e., i can build it and run without any trouble.

But i’ve got some problems with the design tab inside Qtcreator.

First, on all qml file (even with example projects), i have an error message “Using Qt Quick code model instead of Qt Quick2 (M324) (4:1)” and i can’t use the design editor.

Second, on qml files with other import than QtQuick 2.2 (for me QtQml.Models 2.1 and QtQuick.Controls 1.1), the import is underlined in red with the error message “QML module not found”. 
I’ve tried to edit the .pro file by adding QML2_IMPORT_PATH=/home/user/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.1/qtquickcontrols/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ (also tried with QML_IMPORT_PATH), it doesn’t work. 
Then, I tried to add it to my path in a terminal using “export QML_IMPORT_PATH=/home/user/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.1/qtquickcontrols/qml/QtQuick/Controls/” and this time, in the error message, i can see the added path in the error message, but it still doesn’t work.

Anyone has an idea to help me ?

Thx !

Comment: For the designer part you eventually have to (re)build your qml2puppet

Comment: I have tried to build qml2puppet (and even build qtcreator3.1 entierly ) by myself and the problem is still here ...

Comment: I'd recommend asking on the dev mailing list or IRC (#qt-creator), where you're far more likely to find someone who works on Creator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exacly the same problem on arch linux with the same versions of QT and QTcreator.

I included on the file ".qmlproject" the line:

```
importPaths: ["/usr/lib/qt/qml/"]
```

And it worked. The red underline disapeared and can use design now.

Try to find something like "/qt/qml/" on your installation folder and include it on the `importPaths`.